# Is is safe to include the key as part of the data string of a hash_hmac() PHP function?

Tags: php, security, hash, hmac

I need to generate an authentication token to be included in a HTTP GET request to target a remote host for which I have a very limited number of options in terms of authentication.

I need the user to land on that page being automatically authenticated. He/she will have to perform a very specific operation, not to use the whole site.

My idea would be to use the PHP's `hash_hmac()` function the following way:

```
hash_hmac("sha512", $email . $glue . $secret_token . $glue . $_REQUEST["mt"], $secret_token);
```

for I have very few fields my system is sharing with that remote host: they are $email and the $secret_token.

Can it be counterproductive or dangerous to throw in the $secret_token into the data string?

Comment: In what ways ...? No one will be able to deduct what the secret may have been by looking at the hash value alone, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Well... In order to verify the HMAC you need the original message. That message  will include the $secret_token....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the HMAC works with a couple of pieces of information.  You have a shared secret, I presume `$secret_token` in your example, that must remain secret and the message payload that is public.  There is usually a timestamp included in both the message as well as appended to the hash that is used for expiration purposes.  For example:  `$epoch_time . "." . hash_hmac("sha512", $epoch_time . $message, $secret_token);`  The idea is that the message can be checked based on a Unix timestamp to see if it exceeded the delivery window.

> Can it be counterproductive or dangerous to throw in the $secret_token into the data string?

In short, yes. It is not explicitly dangerous, but there is no point to adding a bunch of user supplied (or secret) entropy to the message as hmac is designed for this message to remain public.  The idea behind the hmac is to verify that the message is correct; I.E. authorized, not tampered with and optionally of certain age.

Example for authentication between to systems:

```
POST /api/1.0/resource/action HTTP/1.1
HOST: api.local
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: hmac 1574268077.b8e7ae12510bdfb1812e463a7f086122cf37e4f7

{
  "some": "payload"
}
```

On the receiving server, you would check the authorization header.  The first part (1574268077) tells you how old the message *should be* in seconds. The second part (b8e7ae12510bdfb1812e463a7f086122cf37e4f7) is the hash of the payload and the timestamp.  In this case, you would verify the request by using a `$message` value of `$epoch_time . 
'{"some":"payload"}'`.  Checking the time is simple, `if (time() - $epoch_time > 5 * 60) { throw new Exception("Message expired") }`.  The reason we check the timestamp is to avoid replaying the message by a would-be attacker.  Smaller the window, the harder it is to abuse. I would personally keep a running list of used, but not yet expired tokens in a list somewhere until they expire to be extra sure they cannot be used twice.  Either Redis or Memcached would be good choices to store such a list as expiration can be handled for you by the cache.  A quick note about GET/HEAD and other endpoints that do not accept a request body. The message for these requests is probably the relative uri including query parameters.